# Understanding marginalization in Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning

Tags: probability-theory

On page 374 in Bishop's PRML, he does the following:

If
$$
p(a,b,c) = p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)
$$
then
$$
p(a,b) = p(a)\sum p(c|a)p(b|c) = p(a)p(b|a)
$$

I don't understand how he does the final step, going from the marginalization sum to the very last expression. Could someone derive this step by step?

Many thanks

Comment: If you ignore the middle it is straight from definition of bedingd wahrscheinlichkeit. (conditional probability.)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I missed that. But why then does Bishop bother with the marginalization in the middle?

Comment: I have a copy of Bishop's in a locker ~1000 kilometers from here. I really can't check the context on page 374 from over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)

$$p(b|a) = \frac{p(a,b)}{p(a)}$$

Just use first and last expression and rewrite it and you see it become the same as above definition. The wikipedia just uses a set theoretic expression for above.